# Broadcasting using red5 server

Tags: php, flash, live-streaming, red5

I have to ask you after several days of bad luck with red5 live streaming.

Is possible, to send video from webcam through red5 and recieve video from client side (using rtmp:// protocol)?

Do I need something else apart from webcam (flash) plugin, which will be source of video and VPS with red5 installed?

I tried to use this plugin https://github.com/af83/webcam-streaming

And set rtmp server in this plugin to `rtmp://myVPS-IP:5080/live/` and hoped, that I will be able to get on this url the live stream on client side...

What is the right solution please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to do is possible with red5. I have no experience with the plugin you linked, but in-general, the following protocols are available on the ports below:

```
rtmp - 1935
rtmpt - 5080
rtmpe - 1935
```

Please be aware that the `5080` port is specific to red5 for `http` and `rtmpt`. Lastly, all the ports listed are the defaults and may be changed in the `conf/red5.properties` file.

Comment: Have a look at that, thank you! I think, that I will just need some broadcaster to get video from webcam to that rtmp server. After that, it should be pretty easy to get that back. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: There are a few broadcast options out there for the opensource red5: ffmpeg, fmle, vlc, plain-old flash..